# php session in subdomain via angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, session, get

Hi i have angularjs getting data from a php file in subdomain.

I can display the $_session value by direct accessing the page on the browser by keying the url. However, the same $_session value is null when it is read by angularjs via $http.get.

I have the below is the backend.php

```php
$domain = session_name("domain");

session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');
session_start();

header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");

echo $_SESSION['hello'];
```

controller.js

```js
$http.get( api_url + 'backend.php').success(function(data){
});
```

$_SESSION['hello'] is retrieved if i key in domain.com/backend.php on the browser. However it is null if access through angularjs in the code above. How can i make it readable via angularjs?

It works if it's the same domain, but i am putting the php file in the subdomain.

Comment: If angular can read your session cookie directly then you probably have big security holes. Use a surrogate value (e.g. encrypting the session  id or using a proper SSO solution) when crossing contexts.

Comment: I m not using angularjs to access. But I can't echo the session in php file via angularjs' $http.get. but I can do that if I access the php direct from the browser.

Comment: Read the comment again. It's trivial to make the value available to angular and this has already been described lots of times on SO. But if you do this with your session id you throw your security out of the window.